# jQuery Scroll to Next Div Class with Next / Previous Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, frontend

What I'd like is for the fixed navigation, with NEXT and PREV buttons to basically scroll the page to the next div with the class of "section".

I've setup jQuery to essentially add a click function to the NEXT and PREV hrefs. This click function will then use ScrollTop to move to the next duv with a class of .section.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('div.section').first();
// binds a click event-handler to a elements whose class='display'
$('a.display').on('click', function(e) {
    // prevents the default action of the link
    e.preventDefault();
    // assigns the text of the clicked-link to a variable for comparison purposes
    var t = $(this).text(),
      that = $(this);
      console.log(that.next())    
      // checks if it was the 'next' link, and ensures there's a div to show after the currently-shown one
      if (t === 'next' && that.next('div.section').length > 0) {
      //Scroll Function
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:that.next('div.section').scrollTop()});
  } 
    // exactly the same as above, but checking that it's the 'prev' link
    else if (t === 'prev' && that.prev('div.section').length > 0) {
      //Scroll Function
       $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:that.prev('div.section').scrollTop()});     
  }
});
```

I am currently working on JSfiddle with heavily commented jQuery to help you digest: http://jsfiddle.net/ADsKH/1/

I have a console.log currently checking for (that.next()) to determine what the next .section will be, but it's giving me back some very weird results.

Why this isn't working as intended?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `that` can't find a `.next('.section')` because it's nested inside `.navigation`.

From the jQuery documentation for `.next()`.

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements.

[Here's a working example based on your code](http://jsfiddle.net/aVJBY/)

Comment: Wow what a simple solution!...This was literally racking my brain for a couple of hours.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could anyone give me an idea for why the above code wouldn't work in Firefox?

I've tried wrapping everything in a doc. ready function, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there anything inherent to firefox that would be stopping this from working? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks again for the help! Also if anyone needs an alternative method, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mU5rp/2/) is an example that moves the animation and works in firefox without adding / editing overflow.

Comment: @pdoherty926, out of interest do you know how to extend this so that the next/prev buttons dont get confused if you manually scroll up and down the page?   When I say confused I mean more mess up the user experience, because what happens is that the scroll jumps back to where it was before the manual scroll took place and then scrolls from that point.   What would be much nicer is if it knew where it was in context of full page and next/prev then worked seamlessly from the current page position.

Comment: Is there a way to transform the navigation text (next/prev) to images? or trigger the next/prev button by classes example: `.prevButton` and `.nextButton` so we are able to exchange it to images instead text?