# jQuery Scroll to Next/Previous Div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery; bear with me.
Have been trying to use this simple (but great) solution to next-previous scrolling by pdoherty926:

[jQuery Scroll to Next Div Class with Next / Previous Button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15126163/4371014)

However, after copying the code from his jsfiddle link the scrolling won't work on my page. What am I missing?

I've put it all into an HTML5 page to play with it (will obviously move styles and js to separate linked CSS and JS files):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>scroll test</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div.section').first();
$('a.display').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var t = $(this).text(),
that = $(this);
if (t === 'next' && $('.current').next('div.section').length > 0) {
var $next = $('.current').next('.section');
var top = $next.offset().top;   
$('.current').removeClass('current');
$('body').animate({
scrollTop: top     
}, function () {
$next.addClass('current');
});
} else if (t === 'prev' && $('.current').prev('div.section').length > 0) {
var $prev = $('.current').prev('.section');
var top = $prev.offset().top;
$('.current').removeClass('current');
$('body').animate({
scrollTop: top     
}, function () {
$prev.addClass('current');
});
} 
});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.section {background-color:gray; height:440px; margin-bottom:20px;}
.navigation {position:fixed; right:50px; top:10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="navigation">
<a href="#" class="display">next</a><br>
<a href="#" class="display">prev</a>
</div>
<div id="one" class="section current">
One
</div>
<div id="two" class="section">
Two
</div>
<div id="three" class="section">
Three
</div>
<div id="four" class="section">
Four
</div>
</div>
```

Any and all help/advice very welcome.

Comment: Please add the jsfiddle with your code that does not work.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: we need more info, can you post your code, are there any error message?S

Comment: Why don't you just use jquery.scrollTo plugin !?

Comment: Thanks for the help - schoolboy error (as always).

Answer (score 0):

I got your script on **jsfiddle** 
And You just need to use *Jquery* **1.8.3** instead of **1.9.1**.
so change your *jquery* *library* with the version **1.8.3**

Please insert the following jquery library

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the html, css and js is functional, you're probably using an outdate jQuery library. see working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/200/

you need to use jQuery version 1.11 or higher. version 2+ is more preferrable (but sometimes it doesnt work well with IE<9, whereas 1.11 is stable for IE<9)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the jquery library script instead of following

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Update as following:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Actually you are not writing **HTTP:** protocol which is not getting the jquery library from *googleapis*