# Scroll to next section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

My code looks like this:

```
<div id="arrow">
    <a class="next"></a>
    <a class="previous"></a>
</div>

<section id="first">
...
</section>

<section id="second">
...
</section>

<section id="third">
...
</section>
```

The element `#arrow` has `position: fixed`, and I'm trying to make the window scroll to the next `section` when `a.next` is clicked.

Ex: The first time `a.next` is clicked, the window scrolls to `section#first`, the second time, the window scrolls to `section#second`, etc. The same thing happens to `a.previous`.

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

---

**EDIT**

My JS code:

```
$('#arrows a.previous').click(function() {
    $.scrollTo($(this).closest('section').prev(),800);
});

$('#arrows a.next').click(function() {
    $.scrollTo($(this).closest('section').next(),800);
});
```

Comment: Is that a vertical or horizontal scroll?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aVJBY/ This is what you want

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125703/jquery-scroll-to-next-div-class-with-next-previous-button

Comment: @paul Fitzgerald this is not a good example since it does not take care of manual scrolling

Answer (score 4):

You will need to handle to 3 events in this case:

1. Current page position - updated each time.
2. User scrolls manualy the page.
3. User clicks the prev or next button.

2, 3 need to use the current page position and update him according to the direction that the page is scrolling.

My quick demos : [**Vertical Version jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shlomohassid/6r1h687k/)  ---  [**Horizontal Version jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shlomohassid/8sjfu9jj/)

Vertical Version snippet :

```js
$(function(){
    
    var pagePositon = 0,
        sectionsSeclector = 'section',
        $scrollItems = $(sectionsSeclector),
        offsetTolorence = 30,
        pageMaxPosition = $scrollItems.length - 1;
    
    //Map the sections:
    $scrollItems.each(function(index,ele) { $(ele).attr("debog",index).data("pos",index); });

    // Bind to scroll
    $(window).bind('scroll',upPos);
    
    //Move on click:
    $('#arrow a').click(function(e){
        if ($(this).hasClass('next') && pagePositon+1 <= pageMaxPosition) {
            pagePositon++;
            $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
                  scrollTop: $scrollItems.eq(pagePositon).offset().top
            }, 300);
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('previous') && pagePositon-1 >= 0) {
            pagePositon--;
            $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
                  scrollTop: $scrollItems.eq(pagePositon).offset().top
              }, 300);
            return false;
        }
    });
    
    //Update position func:
    function upPos(){
       var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop();
       var $cur = null;
        $scrollItems.each(function(index,ele){
            if ($(ele).offset().top < fromTop + offsetTolorence) $cur = $(ele);
        });
       if ($cur != null && pagePositon != $cur.data('pos')) {
           pagePositon = $cur.data('pos');
       }                   
    }
    
});
```

```css
section { min-height:800px; }
#arrow {
    position:fixed; 
    right:0; 
    top:0;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
#arrow a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px 20px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="arrow">
    <a class="next">next</a>
    <a class="previous">prev</a>
</div>
<section style="background-color:green">...</section>
<section style="background-color:blue">...</section>
<section style="background-color:red">...</section>
```

Comment: This was just what I was looking for, thank you!

I extended your function to use one nav for going down the page, and once you hit the last item, scroll back to the top: [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/cgq6cjtn/)

Answer (score 3):

All you need, to allow the user to use both arrows and scrollbar:

```js
var $sec = $("section");
$(".prev, .next").click(function(){
    var y = $sec.filter(function(i, el) {
        return el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 0;
    })[$(this).hasClass("next")?"next":"prev"]("section").offset().top;
    $("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop: y});
});
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
#arrow{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
#arrow a{
  display:inline-block;
  background: tomato;
  padding:6px 15px;
  border-radius:3px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
section{
  height:1200px;
  border:3px solid #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="arrow"><a class="prev">&uarr;</a><a class="next">&darr;</a></div>
<section>1</section>
<section style="height:500px;">2</section>
<section>3</section>
<section style="height:600px;">4</section>
<section>5</section>
```

---

To explain the jQuery a bit:

```
// Cache your selectors
var $sec = $("section"); 

// On any of both arrows click
$(".prev, .next").click(function(){

    // We need to get current element
    // before defining the `.next()` or `.prev()` element to target
    // and get it's `offset().top` into an `y` variable we'll animate to.
    // A current element is always the one which bottom position
    // (relative to the browser top) is higher than 0.
    var y = $sec.filter(function(i, el) {
        return el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 0;
    })[$(this).hasClass("next")?"next":"prev"]("section").offset().top;
    // (Line above:) if the clicked button className was `"next"`,
    // target the the `.next("section")`, else target the `.prev("section")`
    // and retrieve it's `.offset().top`

    $("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop: y});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to do with .closest("section") but it only works when the section is a parent of the element you clicked so this is the best way i got

```js
sections=$("section");
s=0;

$(".next").click(function() {
if(s<sections.length-1){
s++;
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: sections.eq(s).offset().top
}, 500);
}});

$(".previous").click(function() {
if(s>0){
s--;
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: sections.eq(s).offset().top
}, 500);
}});
```

```css
section{
    background-color:#bbb;
    width:100%;
    height:700px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #eee;
}
#arrow{
    position:fixed;

}

#first{
 background-color: red;
}
#second{
 background-color:green;
}
#third{
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="arrow">
    <a class="next">next</a>
    <a class="previous">prev</a>
</div>

<section id="first">
...
</section>

<section id="second">
...
</section>

<section id="third">
...
</section>
```

Comment: Seems like your code will mess things up if you mix arrows and scrollbar user actions. Also it's good to use `.stop()` before allowing the user to go hysteric with clicks.